# Are CUDA CUBIN objects backward compatible?

Tags: c, cuda, shared-libraries

My application uses CUDA kernels for the bulk of the computations. For good reasons (out of scope of this question) I use a shared object/linking model to dynamically load the object files each of which contains 1 host function and 1 CUDA kernel. Since kernels can not be `extern` the basic structure of such a kernel is:

```
__global__ kernel() { ...code... }

extern "C" void call_kernel() {
  <<<GRID,BLOCK,SHMEM>>>kernel();
}
```

I use a host function which sole purpose is to call the kernel. For building the shared object i use:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_20 -m64 --compiler-options -fPIC,-shared -link -o kernel0.o kernel0.cu
```

The whole app uses lots of these kernels and they are loaded with `dlopen()`. The whole thing works fine if everything (building/loading/executing) stays on one machine A.

But when I compile/build the shared objects say on machine B (cuda 4.1, NVIDIA C2050), and `dlopen` them later on machine A (cuda 4.0, GTX 480) the computation does not yield the same result as if the shared objects were also build on machine A.

That sounds odd to me. Isn't there a CUBIN object embedded in the `.o` file which contains instructions that are independent of the particular GPU architecture?

I know that it is advised to use the same compiler version for building and linking. Again, I have good reasons why not to build the shared objects on the same machine as they are executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the first point to make is that you aren't using CUBIN files at all in your application, you are using CUDA fat binary objects. The two things are not the same.

But that isn't the source of your problem. Your problem is with the CUDA runtime library. The runtime API is versioned, and any code compiled for a given runtime API version must be run with that version. Further, runtime API library versions have minimum driver version requirements. You can't take an application built against the CUDA 4.1 library and expect to run it on a machine with CUDA 4.0 library. NVIDIA's recommended way of distributing runtime API code is to distribute the runtime API library (libcudart) with your application, and specify a minimum driver version which your code requires. That ensures the application will run correctly (minimum driver version brings minimum CUDA driver API version, and the distributed runtime API library brings completes the requirements).

The alternative would be to really use cubin files and use the CUDA driver API. It is much more portable (within the minimum driver version requirements), but it also is more work in your host code. The choice is yours.

Comment: Right, I used the word CUBIN synonymously for 'whatever hides in the .o' file. Okay, good point. I guess I will then change to the driver API. Thanks!